# Or statements problem in python

Tags: python, boolean-logic

Or statements in python do not seem to work as in other languages since:

```
-1 < 0 | 0<0
```

returns `False` (should return true since `-1<0` is `True`)

What is the problem?

Comment: What makes you call this an "or statement"?  What tutorial did you see this in?  Can you provide a link or a quote?

Comment: Notice that most other languages parse this *identical* to Python. You probably confused `|` with `||` (used e.g. in C and Java). (Other languages will evaluate the expression differently to Python though, but that is unrelated to the bitwise or operator, and instead to the way Python has special treatment for statement such as `x < y < z` which is missing from other languages.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two problems: First, the precedence of the operators is not what you expect.  You can always add parens to make it explicit:

```
>>> (-1 < 0) | (0 < 0)
True
```

Also, single-pipe is a logical or that evaluates both of its arguments all the time.  The equivalent of other languages's pipe-pipe is `or`:

```
>>> -1 < 0 or 0 < 0
True
```

Comment: My 2.6.6 Python prompt printed "True"

Comment: My bad, I typo'd and had `(-1 < 0) | (0 | 0)`

Answer (score 1):

`|` has precedence over `<` (see the [Python operator precedence table](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary)). Use parenthesis to force the desired order of operation:

```
>>> -1 < 0 | 0 < 0
False
>>> -1 < (0 | 0) < 0
False
>>> (-1 < 0) | (0 < 0)
True
```

You might prefer to use the [boolean `or`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#or) operator (equivalent to `||` in many other languages) instead of the [bitwise `|`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), which will give you the desired precedence without parenthesis:

```
>>> -1 < 0 or 0 < 0
True
```

As a side note, `-1 < 0 < 0` (or `a < b < c`) does the [intuitive thing](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin) in Python. It is equivalent to `a < b and b < c`. Most other languages will evaluate it as `(a < b) < c`, which is not typically what you'd expect.